# Durandal Mobile Views

Tags: mobile, durandal, sammy.js

Does anyone have a solution that will allow you to create a desktop and mobile view for a single viewmodel in Durandal?

Ideally I would like to take a page from MVC4 and have a view.html and view.mobile.html for each viewmodel and just direct the browser to the relevant one based on userAgent string.

**Edit 1**
Looks like I can override the View Locator's convertModuleIdToViewId function, solution to follow.

Comment: I believe there is an open source solution sitting around somewhere that tackled this, I will see if I can dig anything up

Comment: Durandal uses boostrap to design a responsive web site. Boostrap is sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile first front-end framework for faster and easier web development.